# Nodejs route for catch not found page collide with react server side static index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using React and NodeJs. I am using it in the same folder. in the parent folder I have the client folder (containing React), server folder (with node), and package JSON file that executes the build of the react inside a 'public' folder named in the server file.

I set the Index html page as static with express JSON, and created the main route: `app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.status(200).sendFile('index.html'))`;

Below, I set the catch all the rest of the routes and set them the 404 status and send them a message: `app.use('*', (req, res, next) => { res.status(404).send('Not found...') });`;

[image]

The main page works, but when I try to access a not existing route I have a path error

Comment: Try to remove '*' and call just the callback like `app.use((req, res ...) => etc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Its the error about the `index.html` its relative path. Not absolute one.

`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"))` should fix that error. Added the public as you mentioned that the `React` is setup to build files inside public on server. Make sure you import `path` with `const path = require('path');`.

For your requirement and react setup, here is what I suggest.

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const apiRoutes = require('./express-api-routes');


const app  = express();

// everything on public folder will be server statically
app.use("/", express.static("public"));

// all the /api requests goes here
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);

// 404 error page will be handeled by react.
app.use("*", (req, res) =>{
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html")) 
});

app.listen(3000);
```